# Changing for loop to while loop for regex

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

How do I change this for loop to while loop?

```
String [] strArray = testcontent.split(Pattern.quote("SolrDocument{content=["));

for (String str : strArray) {
  System.out.println("TestSplit: " + str);
}
```

I am new to Java.

Comment: google `how to iterate over array using while loop in java`. Have some research efforts then post the question here.

Comment: All for-loops are essentially glorified while-loops - and a for-each loop is a glorified for-loop. Convert it to a normal for-loop first, then it should be evident.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = 0;

while(index < strArray.length)
{
  system.out.println(strArray[index]);
  index++;
}
```